# Add class/index based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Basically I want the user that depending on the url they selected for the website a different background will come.

Example :

example.com/#red <- red bg

example.com/#blue <- blue bg

My idea was to have that index added and to use it as a style class but it didn't workout.

I looked all over the internet and couldn't find anything that worked or matched. I'm completely lost ....

I tried:

```
if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/#red"){
   $('body').addClass('red');
} else if(window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/#blue"){
  $('body').addClass('blue');
                     ---[10 more colors]---
} else {
exit();
}
```

Comment: Using php, you can easily add body class to your markup before page is loaded. Then in the css have css for that body class ... https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by index, but with your current example you can use location.hash, and remove the first character:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var color = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    $('body').addClass(color);
});
```

For checking you could replace the if/else comparisons with a switch, or put the matching colors in an array and if `color` matches any then do the addClass.

EDIT: for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var matchColors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    var color = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    if (matchColors.indexOf(color) != -1){
        $('body').addClass(color);
    }
});
```

Also, instead of hash, did you consider using url parameters? (which can be retrieved using location.search)